# Convert Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] to List[String]

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to read a file. I need to read this file by line into a list.

```
val res: stream.scaladsl.Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = Ftp.fromPath(Paths.get(uri), ftpSettings)
```

How can I convert the res value to List[String]?

Comment: I already tried these flows. But I don't want a String, I want to get List[String]


res.via(Framing.delimiter(
      ByteString("\n"),
      maximumFrameLength = 256,
      allowTruncation = true))
      .map(_.utf8String)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flow in your comment looks like a good starting point.
Try and run it against a `Sink.seq`.

```
  val f: Future[Seq[String]] = res
    .via(Framing.delimiter( ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 256, allowTruncation = true))
    .map(_.utf8String)
    .runWith(Sink.seq)

  val list: Seq[String] = Await.result(f, 10.seconds)
```